# 1100 Sequence Detector

Tags: vhdl

I have to design a 1100 sequence detector using Mealy model and JK Flip-Flops. Here is the state diagram:

[image: State diagram]

And based on this diagram, I obtain following input statements for flip-flop inputs (A and B flip-flops):

```
JA = A and X
KA = B
---------------
JB = A xor X
KB = A nand X
```

Finally, VHDL implementation gives these result:

[image: Simulation result]

But it catches "110" instead of "1100". When I implement same state diagram using **case...when** structure, it gives correct result but I have to use logic gates & JK flip-flops.

How should I change this design? Is there something wrong or something I missed?

**EDIT:** I need obtain functions JA, KA, JB, KB (which are inputs of JK flip-flops) in terms of present states A,B and input sequence X.

[image]

Comment: X denotes `sequence input`, A is output of first JK, and B is for second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the tables and K-Maps, I came up with a completely different result than what you got.  Here are my tables and K-Maps.

[image]

Your equations also seem much too simple.  Can you post a picture of your K-Maps?

**Edit**

Okay, looks like everything you posted is correct.  I didn't know this until I read around today, but it looks like Mealy machines have this interesting situation with their output.

From [a page](http://www2.elo.utfsm.cl/~lsb/elo211/aplicaciones/Pennsylvania/abelex1.html) of University of Pennsylvania's Electrical Engineering:

[image]

So the output is correct. I built the circuit according to my equations and confirmed it does work this way.  The output goes high on 110, and then back low again on the 2nd 0, so the output is a pulse.  That makes sense, because Mealy machines don't have constant outputs while residing in states like Moore Machines do, only in between the states.  Unfortunately my laptop died so I can't link you the circuit.

This is also consistent with your output waveform, as your output goes low again after the 2nd 0 in 1100.

Now you might be wondering that if you input the sequence 1101, then the output still goes high for a brief moment.  That's true, and they cover that situation in the U-penn website as well, in the 2nd picture where they talk about the "glitch" in the output.

From their page:

*One notices that there is a glitch in the output after the input sequence 10111010. However this occurs at a moment that the output is not valid (the output is valid just before the positive clock edge). The valid output sequence is than 000100000 as expected.*

Remember their sequence detects 1011, so the last 4 bits of their input sequence, 1010, is the same glitch situation as if 1101 was input to yours. Looks like nothing is wrong.

Comment: I've added state assignment/truth table.

Comment: Thanks for your help! And the keyword is: "Synchronous Mealy Machine". The result that we desire is simply obtained when current output pass through an additional D-FlipFlop (or a JK that is converted to D, for this example). [Details are here.](http://www2.elo.utfsm.cl/~lsb/elo211/aplicaciones/Pennsylvania/abelex3.html)